# How to store data from session using Express-session

Tags: node.js, express, session

Here is my function:

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res ,next) {


console.log(req.session);
var userForCheck =  req.session.user_name;
console.log(user);
}
```

in my console screen it's printed out req.session like this :

```
Sess {
 cookie:
  { path: '/',
   _expires: 2018-11-16T03:18:31.896Z,
   originalMaxAge: 59999,
  httpOnly: true }
user: { user_name: 'given001', password: '123' } }
```

but the user variable is

```
 undefinded
```

how can i store user_name in userForCheck variable without undefined?

Comment: in your code, `user` will always be undefined, because you never assign it.  Try: `var user = req.session.user` and then `console.log(user)`.   From there you can use `user` like `console.log(user.user_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it should be like,

```
var userForCheck =  req.session.user.user_name;
```

Hope this helps!